# Why does ammonia have a pKa of 32.5 at −33 °C?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia), ammonia has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $32.5$ at $\pu{-33 °C}.$  Why does it say that? Is it a typo? Isn't anything above $12$ is a very strong base? And both bases and acids are slightly stronger at higher temperatures, not lower, correct?

Comment: That is the boiling point of ammonia. Pure liquid ammonia will have different properties than ammonia in solution. Also, when you switch solvents, it becomes difficult to compare pKa values.

Comment: The reaction described by the pKa of ammonia is $$\ce{NH3 <=> NH2- + H+}$$ In water, ammonia acts as base. A pKa of 32.5 means that the amide anion $\ce{NH2-}$ is a strong base. The temperature dependence is determined by whether the reaction is endothermic or exothermic.